# Finite Characteristic of a Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, positive-characteristic

If $H$ is a ring and it has a finite non-zero characteristic $p$ then ring is finite.

I couldn’t any counter example for this claim. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Just searching “positive characteristic infinite” yields the dupe and its duplicates. Please search first next time.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/p$ it has characteristic $p$ and it is infinite.

Comment: Thank you so much